# Wicket ignores 302 redirect from Spring

Tags: javascript, spring, redirect, wicket

I have an Angular + spring REST and Wicket hybrid application. 
Wicket serves a UserPage class. This UserPage contains my javascript page.

```
public class UserPage extends WebPage {

public UserPage() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forUrl("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"));
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(new JavaScriptResourceReference(UserPage.class, "user.js")));
    response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(new CssResourceReference(UserPage.class, "user.css")));
}
```

I have implemented a Filter to check if a session is active, if this is not the case, the page should redirect.

```
WicketSession s = WicketSession.get();

if (s == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("/");
} else if (s.getUser() == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("/");
} else {
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

However, when i run this page without logging in, the browser receives 302 but does not redirect. This only happens when the page is served through wicket. If i manually go to UserPage.html, it does redirect.

Anyone know anyway why this is happening? It surely is wicket speficic, and im not that familiar with wicket yet.

When trying to reach /user, the page stays, and the html body is send as response data, which my script tries to parse and fails (hence all the empty checkboxes)
[image]

When manually going to UserPage.html, it does redirect.
[image]

Does anyone know why wicket does not redirect when its being sent a 302? Any clues on a possible fix?

Comment: How did you define your filterChain? If the wicketFilter is behind your own Filter Wicket shouldn't be able to interfere.

Comment: Ah yes the wicket filter was in fact executed before the spring filter.
They now both redirect, but this has caused another issue.
when i call get() on the WicketSession within the spring filter, it throws an org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: There is no application attached to current thread.

Comment: That was what actually got me to ask this. Usually you'll need to add the WicketSessionFilter to your chain to make Wicket objects (like the Session) available to non-wicket code. Still it's recommended to put the wicket filter in front of it (If this page sometimes can be delivered by Wicket) ... Maybe you want to look into Wicket Authentication and redirect to a specific page when no user is logged into the session?

Answer (score 1):

1) If you keep the session data in WicketSession then it should be before Spring's Filter/Servlet in web.xml.

I would suggest to keep the user in Spring Security Authentication if you use it.

2) `WicketSession.get()` never returns `null`. It acts as "get or create". You need `if (WicketSession.exists()) {...}` instead.